# how can i get list of values in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having an odd problem with LINQ, and I am hoping someone can explain to me what is going on.

I have a model:

```
public class AnswerModel
{
   public string Question { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get a list of all answers depending on questions in a view like this:

```
q1 a1a2a3a4

q2 a1a2a3a4

and so on
```

Comment: "In a view". What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var q = db.Answers.Where(a => a.Question == "q1")
       .SelectMany(a => a.Answers).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dic = list.ToDictionary<string, string>(t=>t.Question, t=> t.Answers == null ? string.Empty : String.Join(',', t.Answers.Select(t=>t.Name));
```

it will be:

q1 a1,a2,a3,a4

q2 a1,a2,a3,a4

you can replace ',' to String.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
var view = AnswerModels
    .Select(am => new
                      {
                          am.Question, 
                          Answers = string.Join("", am
                                                    .Answers
                                                    .Select(a => a.ToString())
                                                    .ToArray())
                      });
```